# Does break statement inside if inside while finish "while loop" completely or only immediate "if"?

Tags: android, if-statement, break, do-while, boolean-logic

I have this code, that caused me error. The code goes through list and sees if any user is logged in, if it is logged in it counts which user it is - first or second.

When i placed that break statement inside if, the loop only found the first user and did not do anything about 2nd user - **the entire loop was ending!** How so? I thought the break only works for the immediate block it is placed within, i.e. if break is in if{}, it breaks out of this if and the code execution continues.

Does break statement end even the outside loops?

```
            do {
            if (userlogin){
                if(how_many_logged_in == 0){
                    name1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }
                else if(how_many_logged_in == 1){

                    name2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    break ; //this is confusing - where does it break from?                  
                }
            }
        } while (condition);
```

Comment: It will quit the loop, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Comment: >break inside while or dowhile loop ,works like goto statement .It's a break point in ur loop.

Comment: Why do you even need a break there if you want to continue? There's no code after it anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [java language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15), `break` ends abruptly the innermost enclosing `switch`, `while`, `do`, or `for` control structure. So, `if/then/else` are simply ignored.

Comment: Not only in java even in .Net ,C and C++ , javascript and other languages also have same concepts.break is used to get out of a loop or in switches it prevents other cases to execute

Answer (score 1):

As [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) says,**break** is used to leave most nearest loop,for example:

`while(***){break;}`

`do{break;}while(***)`

`switch`

`for`
,but doesn't work in statements like `if`.